# Sens de "sous peine d’une amende"

Tags: sens, expressions

Du [Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/ligue-1/article/2017/05/18/ligue-1-cinq-chiffres-fous-et-quatre-autres-un-peu-inquietants-qui-resument-le-succes-de-monaco_5129803_1616940.html):

> Lorsque l’UEFA a sanctionné Monaco en 2015 pour ses budgets en déficit, le club s’est engagé à être à l’équilibre en 2016-17, **sous peine d’une amende** de dix millions d’euros.

"sous peine d’une amende": Est-ce que ça veut dire que Monaco a déjà payé cette amende, ou qu'il devrait la payer s'il échouait à être à l’équilibre?

Comment: I understand your confusion and I can even see (because of the use of “s’engager”, which can mean “to make a formal promise/commitment”) a third possible interpretation falling between the two extremes that you mention: i.e., “Under the threat of a big fine, the club formally agreed to balance its budget.” This could mean that the threat of the fine was used to obtain the formal promise and that even if, in spite of its good faith promise/efforts, the club  falls short of totally meeting the promised goal (e.g., if ticket/product sales fall) the fine won’t automatically be imposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'expression "sous peine de" introduit ce qui se passerait dans le cas contraire. L'action n'est donc pas encore réalisée, mais le sera si la condition n'est pas remplie.

Ici, Monaco devra payer l'amende si le club n'est pas à l'équilibre pour la saison 2016-2017.

On peut l'apparenter à l'expression "au risque de".

Answer (score 1):

Voici un extrait de [peine](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peine) du cnrtl, *§ I.C.2*

> 2. Sous peine de + subst., verbe à l'inf.(dr.). **Si on ne veut pas être passible de (telle peine).** Tout juge de paix (...) est tenu d'office (...), sous peine d'être poursuivi comme complice de détention arbitraire, de s'y transporter aussitôt (Code instr. crim., 1808, p.792).L'enseignement primaire devint obligatoire, sous peine, pour les parents et leurs complices, de sanctions pénales (Encyclop. éduc., 1960, p.96).
>      − P. ext. Si l'on ne veut pas courir le risque de. Le médecin lui enjoint, sous peine de mort, de rentrer à Paris (Lemaitre, Contemp., 1885, p.330).Il est temps de songer à remettre de l'essence, sous peine de tomber en panne «sèche» 20 ou 30 km plus loin (Chapelain, Techn. automob., 1956, p.338).
>      ♦ Sous peine de vie (vx). Sous peine de mort. [Ils] écartent les soldats, leur défendent sous peine de vie d'approcher du roi (Chateaubr., Ét. ou Disc. hist., t.4, 1831, p.157).

Answer (score 0):

Cela veut dire que Monaco devrait payer cette amende au cas où l'équilibre ne serait pas atteint.

Answer (score 0):

If your native language is English, then *sous peine de* is the same as *on (under) pain of*.